# Passing A SImple List Correctly

Tags: c++, list, qt, parameter-passing

I am new to Qt and c++. I am having difficulty passing a list of points to a method. When I declare the list globally and use it it works fine but when I declare it locally and pass it to a method it doesnt work at all.(By doesnt work at all I mean the vehicle doesnt have a list of points to follow o it does nothing as opposed to hen its declared globally it works fine)

```
Simulation::Simulation()
{
    QList<QPointF> pointsToFollow3;
    pointsToFollow3  <<QPointF(0,25)<<QPointF(300,25)<<QPointF(1000,25)<<QPointF(1700,25);
    createVehicles(5, pointsToFollow3);
}
void Simulation::createVehicles(int numberOfVehicles, QList<QPointF> pointsToFollow)
{
    spawnVehicle(pointsToFollow);       
}

void Simulation::spawnVehicle(QList<QPointF> pointsToFollow)
{
    //spawn my vehicle
    Vehicle * vehicle = new Vehicle(pointsToFollow);
    vehicle->setPos(pointsToFollow[0]);
    scene->addItem(vehicle);
}
```

This works when points to follow is declared in the header file as a public global variable, I think the way I am passing the list of points is incorrect and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to declare and define `pointsToFollow3` in the constructor of `Simulation` class.

Comment: Can you post the code in a non working situation?  It's hard to fix working code.

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal example that readers can try.

Comment: That code isnt working

Comment: My question is how do I pass a list into a method?

Comment: It is declared in the constructer @vahancho

Comment: You can pass it by reference if you need to do some modifications on it : QList<QPointF>& pointsToFollow)

Comment: I'm just wondering how you have access to the new `vehicle`, because you lost track of `Vehicle * vehicle` immediately after `spawnVehicle()` returns.

Comment: Please make this an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would avoid passing lists by value, instead try passing by reference, i.e. `void Simulation::spawnVehicle(QList<QPointF>& pointsToFollow)`

Comment: @user2079139, from the code you posted, it does not defined in the constructor - it is defined... nowhere. Please show the actual code.

Comment: @vahancho it is now :) All I want to do is pass the values in the list to the methods so they can be used that is all

Comment: The usage of the QList is correct (QLists are implicitly shared, you can pass them by reference but that will just save a couple of bits and one atomic operation, bjpelcdev). Maybe you should look for the error in user3528438's comment.

Comment: @Christian I know the problem 

        Can you pass local varibales when using signals and slots itn Qt



    QList<QPointF> pointsToFollow3 ;
    pointsToFollow3  <<QPointF(0,25)<<QPointF(300,25)<<QPointF(1000,25)<<QPointF(1700,25);
    vehicleSpawned=0;
    maxNumberOfVehicles= numberOfVehicles;
    connect(spawnTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(spawnVehicle(pointsToFollow3)));
    spawnTimer->start(1000);

Comment: @user2079139 ```connect(spawnTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(spawnVehicle(pointsToFollow3)));``` will not work. You have to define a slot which calls ```spawnVehicle(pointsToFollow3))```. In C++11 and Qt5 you can use lambdas.

Comment: Could it be that the Vehicle class takes a list of points by reference?

Comment: Where do you check the contents of the list to know that they are not what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0):

Its really difficult to understand what do you mean, moreover you attach worked code, of cource not ideal, but worked.

After reading yours comments i try to realize something like you want to do.

Your header class `Simulation`:

```
#include <QObject>

class QGraphicsScene;
class QTimer;
class QPointF;

class Simulation: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Simulation(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Simulation();

private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QList<QPointF*> *list;
    QTimer *timer;

private slots:
    void spawnVehicle();
};
```

And it's realization:

```
Simulation::Simulation(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    list = new QList<QPointF*>;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        list->append(new QPointF(i*100, 25));

    timer = new QTimer;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(spawnVehicle()));
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

At this method just write to console yours list's elemets:

```
void Simulation::spawnVehicle()
{
    static int currentNumber = 0;

    qDebug() << (*list->at(currentNumber++));

    if (currentNumber >= list->size()) {
        timer->stop();
        deleteLater();
    }
}
```

At destructor you must to free resources:

```
Simulation::~Simulation()
{
    delete timer;
    qDeleteAll(list->begin(), list->end());
    list->clear();
    delete list;
    delete scene;    
}
```

At least i want to say, that create `QList<QPointF>` at your constructor isn't really good idea; It isn't wrong, but not OO correctrly i think.

The best way is doing like this:

Define `Simulation(QList<QPointF> *lst, QObject *parent = 0)` constructor with `QList<QPointF> *` parameter, which already created and filled, and handle with this entity.

I hope this example will be usefull for you.